# Angular - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: angular

I have this in my authentication service:

```js
constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router,) {
   //append headers
   // set token if saved in local storage
   var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
   this.token = currentUser && currentUser.token;
   if(this.token){
      this.user_id = currentUser.user.user_id;
   }
}
```

This is underlined:

> localStorage.getItem('user')

But got this error:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

How do I get this resolved?

Thanks

Comment: You need to handle the fact that there might no value in the local storage, that is `null` being returned.

Comment: @GaëlJ - How do I handle this?

Comment: See the réponse by @mbojko below

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you need to check against localStorage entry for key `'user'` not being set. Sth like

```
const userJSON = localStorage.getItem('user');

if (userJSON) {
   // token setting logic goes here
} else {
   // plan B
}
```

Comment: What do I put in // token setting logic goes here  ad also in // plan B

Comment: In the `if` you out what you want to do if the value is found in local storage (basically your original code), in the `else` it depends on you, what you want to do if the value is not found in local storage..

Answer (score 0):

We can directly assign type string or null passing like this

```
var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') ?? '');
```

This will check if the localstorage has the item if not pass '' empty string